# has_many relationship form with ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, has-many

I've been looking for this for an hour now and still haven't found a solution.

I have an `Account` that `has_many :users` and `User` that `belongst_to :account`

On my `admin/account` I want to create a form that let's add those many users to an account, so I did:

```
form(html: { multipart: true }) do |f|
    f.inputs "Account details" do
      f.input :email
      f.input :full_name
      f.input :password
      f.input :birth_date, :as => :datepicker
      f.input :user_ids
      f.input :bio
      f.input :deleted
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

But I get an `unpermmited_parameter: user_ids` error even though I have added it to the `permit_params`:

```
permit_params :email, :password, :deleted, :full_name, :birth_date, :bio, :created_at, :updated_at, user_ids:[]
```

I've seen that if you try to fill a field with the wrong format you get that error, so I tried filling it with ids these ways: "1,2,3"; "1 2 3", [1,2,3]...but still the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
form(html: { multipart: true }) do |f|
  f.inputs "Account details" do
  ...
  f.inputs 'Users' do
    f.input :user_ids, as: :array
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: I'm getting `Unable to find input class ArrayInput`, and according to Formatstic docs, :array is not a valid input value.

Comment: Sorry, I used there the custom input. You can do like this:
f.input :user_ids, as: :select, collection: User.pluck(:name, :id), include_blank: true, multiple: true

Comment: I wanted to avoid using a select, but I think I have no choice. Thanks!
One more thing, do you know how can I edit the "select" height? It's only showing me 4 at a time.

Comment: You should use a custom control for this job. I like select2: https://select2.github.io/

Comment: If you don't want to use a select you can use a text input and parse it inside controller. Also you can use multiple text inputs. In that approach Rails will aromatically parse inputs to the target array. There are many solutions for it. But the better is to use multiselect + ajax search.